# jQueryUI's .tabs is clashing with Apache Rewrite

Tags: jquery-ui, mod-rewrite

I have an Apache write that works everywhere except on pages that are using 'tabs'.

For some reason, the tabs are loading as if they are full pages loaded through AJAX (ran through the index.php as the rewrite instructs - but it shouldn't be rewriting an # anchor link I would think...)

Is there a way that I can stop it from doing this? It's weird because **not only is it treating the # link as a real URL, it's adding -33,000px to the** `<html>` **via inline style**, so this is what it looks like AFTER I disable it in the inspection tool. Otherwise it's just black and extremely long.

[image]

***I should add that this was not an issue until I added `<base href="/folder/">` to fix an issue with it not rewriting sub-directories properly.*** Before, it still did the rewrite and rendered the page correctly.

**Update**
This is definitely a `<base>` and jQueryUI's `.tabs` clashing. When I removed the rewrite and use the long URL it continuously clones them. The rewrite saved it from rewriting past 12 times or so.

Comment: In your .htaccess, the `RewriteCond` that checks for the fragment will only fail if it comes immediately after `/folder/`.  For example, www.example.com/folder/file.php#hello won't match the condition, but www.example.com/folder/#hello will.  If you don't want the rewrite to happen on any request involving /folder/, you probably want `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/folder/.*(#(.*))$`

Comment: Replaced code but it's still going nuts. It works in IE oddly enough.. The rewrite makes it `/folder/#tab` though that's not the physical path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8637) bug report I found a solution.

```
$.fn.__tabs = $.fn.tabs;
$.fn.tabs = function (a, b, c, d, e, f) {
    var base = location.href.replace(/#.*$/, '');
    $('ul>li>a[href^="#"]', this).each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr('href', base + href);
    });
    $(this).__tabs(a, b, c, d, e, f);
};

    //$('#the-object').tabs();
```

Apparently at 1.8 it worked, at 1.9 it went loopy. This adds the base href to the link, fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`mod_rewrite` does also look at the fragment identifiers, but you can tell it not to in a `RewriteCond`.

The following only allows a URI that doesn't end with a fragment identifier.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(#(.*))$
```

Comment: This is really more of a `mod_rewrite` question than a jQuery question.  Can you add the relevant section of your .htaccess to your question?

Comment: Added relevant code. I can't tell that it's rewriting # links anymore in based on the rewrite log.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is partly due to a bug in jQueryUI tabs

[The Bug Report](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4656)

I'm not sure I can wrap my head around this, but it is working in IE and not in Chrome/Firefox... Guess I'll try a plug-in.

Comment: That's a bogus bug report.  It was opened 4 years ago and dropped because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: True, but it's very similar to this issue. For some reason it is now loading the page without the -33000px margin, but it's still making 3+ duplicates of the tabs.

Comment: Another `notabug` reporting `<base>` and `.tabs` clashing. http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8637